# Angular JS - pass string to GET Method and update

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building part of an application using Angular JS and MVC. The part I'm having trouble with is attempting to retrieve data through a GET method from an internal API. This API is linked to a table that has two fields called **cust_code** and **depot_code**. Both these fields are in a second table with the main field **(cust_code)** having the same codes in them but under a slightly different field name **Cust_code** (there is no foreign key between tables). Up to now I have used $routeParam and converted it to a string at the end of my API.

'''

```
$scope.customer_code = $routeParams.custid

$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/intranet/Test/GetTestCH?cust_code=" + $scope.customer_code,
            data: customer_code,
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
               $scope.customer_code = response.data;
            }, function error(response) {

            });
'''
```

and the code behind API

```
'''
[Route("GetTestCH")]
        [HttpGet]

        public Customer_hierarchy GetCustomer(string cust_code)

        {
            BsTestContext entities = new BsTestContext();
            {

                var mycode = (from c in entities.Customer_Hierarchys
                              where c.cust_code == cust_code
                              select c).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                return mycode;

            }
        }
'''
```

I can get the *cust_code* to the API and its visible whilst in debug. However I'm new to angular JS and unsure how to get *cust_code* and also the *depot_code* (not in the GET string) to the API, on to my html page and then to the update form ready for update into the second table.

This is the first table which uses the *cust_code* string in the GET method

'''

```
   public class Customer_heirarchy_new
{

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string RTM { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Cust_Code { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Cust_Name { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public DateTime? Process_DateTime { get; set; } 
}
```

'''

This is the second table that I'm trying to output

```
'''
public class Customer_hierarchy
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string depot_code { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string level_5 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 3)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string level_4 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 4)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string level_3 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 5)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string level_2 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 6)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string level_1 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 7)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string cust_code { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 8)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_1 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 9)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_2 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 10)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_3 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 11)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_4 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 12)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_5 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 13)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_6 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 14)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_7 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 15)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_8 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 16)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_9 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 17)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_10 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 18)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_11 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 19)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_12 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 20)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_13 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 21)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_14 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 22)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_15 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 23)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_16 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 24)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_17 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 25)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_18 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 26)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_19 { get; set; }
        [Column(Order = 27)]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string att_20 { get; set; }

    }

'''
```

Comment: You don't need together select c).ToList().FirstOrDefault(); just select c).FirstOrDefault(); would be enough.

Comment: Okay thanks for that information Sergey. However, what I'm really asking is how do I with this cust_code use it to generate data from the second table?

Comment: You will have to show both of your classes of your tables.

Comment: added the classes above Sergey